# Which SSL certificate is best fit when you want to create slash commands with the help of Slack API?

Tags: web-services, azure, ssl-certificate, slack-api

I want to create and publish a Slack APP on their store. My Slack App will have the slash commands and Slack API needs the HTTPS url(webservice) to run the script on that slash command Hit.

Currently, I am using windows Azure to host my webservice for the slash command and the URL for webservice is http which is acceptable by Slack API and it does not allows self signed certificates.

so my questions are:

1] Which certificates I need to buy in order to convert my webservice from 'HTTP' to 'HTTPS'.

2] As I have hosted my webservice on Winodws azure with help of IIS, is there any different process to buy needed ssl certificates ?

Comment: You could also just use cloudflare and then you wouldn't have to buy any certificates.

Comment: Can't help you with Azure, but any certificate will do as long as it is not self-signed. I use it myself with a cheap certificate from my web server provider and it works nicely